# How can i make my array build faster in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api, httprequest

Ok lets put it in this way,

I am making a api request of a clinic service and the data come as this:

```
{
    "count": 693,
    "next": "http://labprot.com/api/lab/prescriptions?page=2&phase=3",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [ HERE IT COMES DATA ALOT OF IT ]
}
```

The problem is i need to run this same request in a loop of do while to retrive all 693 records bcs it only comes as 10 on each page. and i am using the next, like this:

```
        $array = array();
        
        $client = new Client(); //using GuzzleHttp\Client;
       
        $request = $client->get('https://labprot.com/api/lab/prescriptions?phase=3',[
            'verify' => false,
            //some headers
        ]);

        $reponse = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents());

        foreach($reponse->results as $item){
            $array[]=$item;
        }

        do{
           $request = $client->get($reponse->next,[
            'verify' => false,
             //some headers
            ]);
    
            $reponse = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents());
    
            foreach($reponse->results as $item){
                $array[]=$item;
            }
            
        }while($reponse->next != null);
```

this loop is in my controller and it takes arround of 40 seconds to complete the array with the all information

Comment: The most time-consuming part of this are likely the HTTP requests. Guzzle has a way to perform multiple requests in parallel - so you could create a couple of those URLs upfront (doesn’t look like there is any magic involved with how the URL for the next set of data will look, just the `page` parameter will increase?), but that will likely mean you will be making a couple of “pointless” requests in one way or another, because then you won’t be able to react to the `next` URL being missing. Still, you could do this in chunks of 10, or fifty.

Comment: Have you checked the API documentation first of all though, whether it does not offer any parameter to specify how many results to return for one request? Often they offer a `limit` parameter or similar, so it might just be that you are dealing with an implicit default value of 10 here.

Comment: considered caching any of these responses?

Comment: I am trying to talk with the responsible of the API to get me the route that i need for get all records available in DB but i got no anwsers.I guess i got to wait a little more

Comment: @BallardI I got all responses , but i dont want to do it in this way because it cost a alot of time and other people cant access the website bcs of it, it blocks all the website for around 40sec. Just to do this get, and i can get all in one single blow i can do anything i want with it, and stop having this stupid problems.